# cant connect to server via ssh using vpn

Tags: ssh, vpn, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Long story short, the server ip was blocked because abuse of the spamtrap. to unblock the ip i must connect via ssh to the server, solve the problem and contact the provider so he can unblocke it.

the problem is that i connect to the vpn following the step the provider webpage has but when i try to connect to the server via the ip that the vpn give to me it throw:  `port xx: Bad file number`.

what can i do to connect? i use `softlayer.com` as provider if it help

Answer (score 0):

can you ping the machine?

The issue could be that there is a firewall rule running in the subnet where the ip belongs which is blocking the SSH port. I suggest you log on to the https://control.softlayer.com/ and review if there are any VLAN firewall which is blocking the SSH port.